# How can I check if a string in JavaScript matches a special format?

Tags: javascript, string, format

I have an input field on my website and I want that when I press the button that before the data is sent to the next script that the string is checked if it is in the required format. This should happen in JavaScript.
For example the format is:
[A-Z][0-9][A-Z]-[0-9][A-Z][0-9]

Correct Inputs:
G7Z-8R4
S3H-1B6

Wrong Inputs:
s7Z-b7H
sh5T-bs6

Comment: have you tried anything? where is your problem with the regular expression?

Comment: Use regex matching: `yourString.match(/[A-Z][0-9][A-Z]-[0-9][A-Z][0-9]/)`. If you get an empty array then there are no matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the test method of Regex object.

```js
var pattern = /[A-Z][0-9][A-Z]-[0-9][A-Z][0-9]/;

if(pattern.test(someString)) {
  // someString text matches
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const matches = string.match(/^[A-Z][0-9][A-Z]-[0-9][A-Z][0-9]$/);
```